# Why does text of button not align in the middle?

Tags: html, css

This is html:

```
<button class="btncicle" >+</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btncicle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

I had used  vertical-align or line-height , but text of button still not align to middle.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sx49nv3d/2/)

Why does text of button not align in the middle?

Comment: @D T: Try using `line-height: 5px;`. I think that should bring the text to center. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sx49nv3d/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:
Change the line-height Property.

**line-height: 50%;**

Answer (score 1):

use this

**Increase 1 more pixel**

```css
.btncicle
{border-radius: 50%;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
padding: 0;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 1px solid;
line-height: 50%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<button class="btncicle" >+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set `border:none` for the button, alignment will be fixed.

If you need border for the button,we have an alternate solution. You can set `box-sizing: content-box;`. Actually it is the default value, but in this case it is not applied. So you add it in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `<span>` inside of the button & use `display: flex` for this case.

It's consistent overall, even if you change the button size.

The problem here is that the character `font-size` is kind big. If you decrease the `font-size` or increase the button consistently then the `+` character will be certainly in the middle.

```css
.btncircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.btncircle span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1px;
}


.btncircle2 {
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
}

.btncircle3 {
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btncircle"><span>+</span></button>

<button class="btncircle btncircle2"><span>+</span></button>

<button class="btncircle btncircle3"><span>+</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep line-height less than height and width and u get perfect button.
example:line-height:12px;

```
.btncicle {
border-radius:50%;
width:15px;
height:15px;
padding: 0px;
line-height:12px;
```

}